# How to set mathematics for tinyMCE button text?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce, mathjax

I have made [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gHN8G/20/) tinyMCE with a menu button named `Formula`.This menu button has some menu items.I want to show mathematics for the items text.Or even set markup text for the display text of it and it render it to html and not just show it as in the demo:
for example:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mfrac>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mi>y</mi>
  </mfrac>
</math>
```

How to do this?

Comment: you want to chnage the name of the button ?

Comment: I want to change the display text of it using Mathjax syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to tell tinymce which elements it shall treat as valid and what kind of childnodes those elements may have.
For this you will need to adjust the [valid_elements](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3avalid_elements) and [valid_children](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/configuration%3avalid_children) setting.

Another approach: Use this tinymce plugin: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/tinymce/install.php

Comment: Well,I added valid_elements: "*[*]" to my codes but nothing happend.For the purpose of test I replaced a <p>test</p> in the button text and added valid_elements: "p" and nothing happend again.What should I do?

Comment: create a tinymce fiddle with your tinymce version and insert what you got so far there. i will have a look then

Comment: I have created.The link in the first line of the question I mean.

Comment: It is working greate on tinymce's body text but its not working for the display name of the menus and buttons.Is there any solution to do this?Take a look at Formula menu and the body here:http://jsfiddle.net/gHN8G/26/

Comment: i think your mathml gets treated as a pure string here. a workaround could be to modify the domnodes of the menu after tinymce initialization

Comment: I agree but how can I do that?

I tried:

tinymce.get('id').ready(function () {
//here I did naming
});

But it didnt work.

Comment: But you solved my problem with that tinymce plugin.I wont use that version but now I can download some images from some equation in png format and I will use images instead of the text for my list items.I was looking for this hard.Thank you.;)

Comment: i just had to look for the technical possibilities of showing formulas on websites - so i was able to answer (otherwise i've had no clue) - glad it works now